# httpclient PostAsJsonAsync method not found .net frame work 4 parallel solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, obj).Result;
```

The method `PostAsJsonAsync` is not working in .NET Framework 4.0 even after adding dll -System.Net.Http.Formatting

error observed is -

> Error 1   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified. 
>   The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but
>   not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131045)

please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you install the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`, you will solve your problem. This is the Id of the package.

[image]